# Error in unit testing using instrumentation framework

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robotium, android-testing

Hi I'm new in unit testing. I'm writting unit test cases for a library project.My library contains async network calls only. I have tried robotium and android instrumentation framework to write test case. I'm getting following error

```
----- begin exception -----
      I/TestRunner( 1578): 
I/TestRunner( 1578): junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Add result should be 100 but          was 80
I/TestRunner( 1578):    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
I/TestRunner( 1578):    at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:20)
I/TestRunner( 1578):    at com.mamlambo.article.simplecalc.test.MathValidation.test1AddDecimalValues(MathValidation.java:66)
I/TestRunner( 1578):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
I/TestRunner( 1578):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
I/TestRunner( 1578):    at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
I/TestRunner( 1578):    at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
I/TestRunner( 1578):    at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
I/TestRunner( 1578):    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
I/TestRunner( 1578):    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:115)
I/TestRunner( 1578):    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:133)
I/TestRunner( 1578):    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:118)
I/TestRunner( 1578):    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
I/TestRunner( 1578):    at   android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
I/TestRunner( 1578):    at   android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
I/TestRunner( 1578):    at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
I/TestRunner( 1578):    at   android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1584)
I/TestRunner( 1578): ----- end exception -----
```

whenever conditions fails for eg:`assertTrue(false)` and execution stops abruptly. It must executes other test cases right?? or I'm doing something wrong please help.

Here is my test case

```
 public void test1AddDecimalValues() {

        String mathResult = "80";
        assertTrue("Add result should be " + "100" + " but was "
                + mathResult, mathResult.equals("100"));
    }
```

Comment: how does your other test cases looks like?

Comment: the code works as It is supposed to do. Why do you think that you are getting an error?

Comment: @blackbelt thanks for quick replay. I have run demo unit test cases in that if any test case fails it shows in "failure" section and other test cases runs but in my case test case executions stops is it proper??

Comment: No it is not. Do you have more unit test in the same class?

Comment: @StefanBeike thanks for quick replay. my other test cases contains network calls with a callback after network call executes ui activity notified through callback object. and in callback object i'm writtin code asserttrue(true/false) according to call's response

Comment: @blackbelt yes i have mant test cases i wrote test case for network calls

Comment: user mach pretty covers the possibilities you have...

Comment: @StefanBeike can you explain in detail??

Answer (score 3):

If an assertion fails the current test is aborted. If you want to do other tests regardless of this assertion fails or not; put it in another test method.

I highly recommend this page about [JUnit antipatterns](http://www.exubero.com/junit/antipatterns.html). Keep up the testing spirit!

Comment: hey can you give example i'm new in writtin test cases and if test case fails then how it going behave?? I means it stop executing other test cases??

Comment: thanks for quick response i will check this link thanks for help

Comment: hey 1 more question it is okay if i used android framework for writting  test cases or i have to use robotium or any other third party library??

Comment: @curious_mind No, all other functions starting with "test" will still run. And yes - you may write test cases without robotium. Check out http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html